# Does ChunkedOutput/StreamingOutput features work behind apache httpd mod_jk loadbalancer

Tags: apache, rest, jersey-2.0, mod-proxy, mod-jk

I am trying to use glassfish 4 ,JAX-RS Jersey 2.5.1 to create a web service. 
Web Service code looks like Jersey Example 
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#chunked-output
and works fine locally & directly on server.
very large recordset (1000000  JSON records) from database chunk terminated by  ("\r\n")

```
JKMount /* /myLoadbalancer
JKOptions +FlushHeader
JKOptions +FlushPackets
```

In case of mod_proxy:
Response does not com back and finally errors out for large data set.

```
ProxyPass / ajp://myserver:8601/ flushpackets=on

SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
```

has not shown any effect
Similar behavior is observed for StreamingOutput instead of ChunkedOutput
I would like to know if anybody is using ChunkedOutput/StreamingOutput features behind loadbalancer.